# Show exception on Hangfire Failed tasks

Tags: c#, webforms, hangfire

I'm testing Hangfire to use it in my application 
the task is running as expected 
now i make the task fail with try catch block the exception not showed in Failed tasks in dashboard

then i used log4net it works fine logging the exception to a text file but still not visible in hangfire dashboard what is the problem

Framework 4.7 - WebForms - log4net : 2.0.13.0 , hangfire.core : 1.1.1.0
installed by : Install-Package Hangfire_net40

Code

1- Startup.cs

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
         
        app.UseHangfire(config =>
        {
            config.UseSqlServerStorage("Hangfire_Blog");
            config.UseServer();
        });

    }
```

2- web.Config

[image: WebConfig image]

3- Global.ascx

```
 private static readonly log4net.ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
    private BackgroundJobServer _backgroundJobServer;
    protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        
        
        log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
        JobStorage.Current = new SqlServerStorage("Hangfire_Blog");


        using (var connection = JobStorage.Current.GetConnection())
        {
            foreach (var recurringJob in connection.GetRecurringJobs())
            {
                RecurringJob.RemoveIfExists(recurringJob.Id);
            }
        }

        //create an instance of BackgroundJobServer
        _backgroundJobServer = new BackgroundJobServer();

        //add your recurring job
        RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(() => Code(), "*/2 * * * *");

        // RecurringJob. AddOrUpdate(() => Actualizacoes(), Cron.m();
    }
    [AutomaticRetry(Attempts = 10)]
    public void Code()
    {
        try
        {
            string s = "";
            int n = int.Parse(s);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.Error(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You're logging the exception and swallowing it. Perhaps you need to rethrow (`throw;`) the exception so it bubbles up?

Comment: i tried that the exception does not show in hangfire

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for any one facing the same problem @madreflection Comment was a part of the answer

first Hangfire will not catch the exception in try catch block either remove try catch 
or in the catch log the error the throw it to be catched by hangfire

but most important

```
 [AutomaticRetry(Attempts = 10)]
```

that tag means that hangfire will not consider the task fail until it tries to execute 10 times and all the 10 times fail 
hope some one find it useful

Thanks